# How to test every value from string array in c#?

Tags: c#

Hello I am makimg a firmware check program. And the firmware URL has a bunch of diffrent region URL's. For example AFG TMC EGY. And these all must go at the ending of URL, but I dont want to rewrite the code 3 times. How do I make this into a array and make the app test every of off those region codes.

P.S Im a newbie. I have created the array but further i do not know.

```
string[] regions = new string[3];
regions[0] = "AFG";
regions[1] = "TMC";
regions[2] = "EGY";
```

Comment: You are checking these strings against what? Your question seems to be incomplete

Comment: @Steve You see the 3 letters are region codes. The URL has the 3 letters at the end, and all regions have different firmware versions (newer or older). So i am trying to fetch all of them because there are alot of them and i do not want to just rewrite the whole code. For example ```example.com/AFG``` and ```example.com/TMC``` etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are loooking to append the three regions to a url to check against .. you can run the following loop.

```
    string[] regions = new string[3];
    regions[0] = "AFG";
    regions[1] = "TMC";
    regions[2] = "EGY";
    foreach(string region in regions)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"https://url.com/{region}");
    }

// output:
https://url.com/AFG
https://url.com/TMC
https://url.com/EGY
```

In your code, you would do what you need to do with the URL (instead of simply printing it).

Answer (score 1):

Less code:

```
var regions = new[] { "AFG", "TMC", "EGY" };
Array.ForEach(regions, r => Console.WriteLine($"https://url.com/{r}"));
```

...with an attached [counter-argument](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach/).